# how can i submit form to hash or self

Tags: php, html

i have the following form

```
<form action="#!/search/" method="get" style="display:inline;" id="hdr_q">                      
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td><input id="f_peoples" name="q" class="sb_box" size="40" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="o">
<input type="hidden" value="all" name="st">
</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td width="20px" valign="middle">
<input type="submit" id="sfind" name="find" value="Search"></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

when i hit search button it goes to 
http://domain.com/?q=f&o=0&st=all&find=#!/search/
while i want it to submit to http://domain.com/#!/search/?q=f&o=0&st=all&find=
how can id that

Comment: Have you tried an absolute url in the action?

Comment: noop i haven't tried yet let me know what actually it is..

Comment: An absolute URI is on that starts with the protocol (e.g. http://example.com/). It won't help because you want to preserve the fragment identifier which normal form submission doesn't do.

Comment: Stack overflow is being too smart for it's own good and has linkified the URI (and given it a short label) which should start http:...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as a form is concerned, it makes no sense to "submit" data to a fragment identifier — that is never sent to the server. The query string always comes before the fragment identifier.

If you want to achieve this, you'll need to build the URI using JavaScript and not using standard form submission techniques. Most general purpose JS libraries come with routines to [serialise](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) form data to standard encoded data, this will get you most of the way there.

Answer (score -1):

Set `action=""`. An empty action sends the form to itself.

Also, do you really want to send the value of the submit button as well?
May I suggest, take out the `name="find"` for the submit button.

If you want to have &find= at the end, add a hidden field with no value.

```
<form action="" method="get" style="display:inline;" id="hdr_q">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td><input id="f_peoples" name="q" class="sb_box" size="40" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="o">
        <input type="hidden" value="all" name="st">
      </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td width="20px" valign="middle">
        <input type="hidden" id="find" name="find" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" id="sfind" value="Search"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: but i want to to #!/search/ while if i am on http://domain.com/directory it submits it here

Comment: The question clearly stated that the goal was to submit to "/#!/search/?q=f&o=0&st=all&find=" which this answer fails to achieve (since `action=""` doesn't preserve the fragment identifier).